# Как исправить ошибки в include на Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

[image: i]

Помогите исправить ошибки в `#include`ах. Visual Studio не удается открыть файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, написать 5 слов про ошибку было бы полезнее многисленного повторения "магической фразы" - Вас бы меньше минусовали.
Теперь про ошибку:
у Вас "студия" не видит include - файлов.
Очень короткая теория: 
сборка программы состоит из компиляции и линковки.
компиляция требует "видимости" (то есть зания, откуда взять) include - фалов.
Линковка требует того же для библиотек - например, стандартной библиотеки c++.

как ни странно, на первом этапе освоить все эти премудрости проще в командной строке. Это не потому, что мы здесь все олдскульные, а потому, что VS - это очень мощная среда программирования, которая многое скрывает "под капотом". И там есть ОГРОМНОЕ кол-во неочевидных настроек, с которыми Вы не сможете разбраться до тех пор, пока не будете детально понимать, что нужно сделать для сборки проекта.

Есть несколько путей:
1) можно попробовать настроить VS. Гуглить по словам "visual studio c++ include path"

2) можно делать всё из командной строки. Для этого понадобится установить компилятор и дебаггер. Скорее всего, MS - овский Вам не полоёдет. Советую взять пакет MSYS2, вся уствновка в винде сводится к установке пакета MSYS2 и вводу в окне pacman'а команд

```
pacman -Sy
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

3) Можно использовать более "легковесную" среду разработки, у которой не так много неочевидных настроек. Например, Visual studio code или code blocks.
Но нужно помнить, что эти среды разработки представляют из себя только "клей" для консольных утилит: у них нет своего компилятора и дебаггера, они просто правильным образом вызывают уже установленные в систему. то есть пункт 2 из моего списка Вам для этого будет необходим. И настроить такую легковесную среду разработки под свою систему - это тоже отдельная задача - но на решена много раз, есть даже видео на ютьюбе.

А так - успехов,  практика показывает, что во всём можно разобраться!

Comment: MSYS2 за одно выполнение команды `pacman -Sy` не обновится. Нужно сделать `pacman -Syuu`, потом он попросит закрыть окно терминала на крестик, и ту же самую команду нужно будет ввести еще раз.

Comment: Спасибо! видимо, с того раза, как последний раз устанавливал - уже успел забыть

Comment: Чтобы компилировать из командной строки, не обязательно что-то устанавливать, достаточно запустить собственно командную строку разработчика Visual Studio. Если проблема именно в IDE, а не в наборе инструментов, компиляция из командной строки должна ее отсечь.